# Purpose of __repr__ method?

Tags: python

```
def __repr__(self):
  return '<%s %s (%s:%s) %s>' % (
    self.__class__.__name__, self.urlconf_name, self.app_name,
    self.namespace, self.regex.pattern)
```

What is the significance/purpose of this method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \_\_str\_\_ and \_\_repr\_\_ in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: For Java developers who are learning Python, the best way to look at this is as toString() in Java.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

`__repr__` should return a printable representation of the object, most likely *one* of the ways possible to create this object. See official documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr). `__repr__` is more for developers while `__str__` is for end users.

A simple example:

```
>>> class Point:
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...             self.x, self.y = x, y
...     def __repr__(self):
...             cls = self.__class__.__name__
...             return f'{cls}(x={self.x!r}, y={self.y!r})'
>>> p = Point(1, 2)
>>> p
Point(x=1, y=2)
```

Comment: lazy1: I primarily wanted to fix the formatting (it's useful to have examples match up as close as possible with what they'll see in a sample session), but I also tweaked the output format to explicitly be different from the assignment, as that greatly improves the clarity for someone confused over this, imho. (If I've gone to far, just re-edit, and I'll owe you a beer.)

Comment: Omitted the reference: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

Comment: This should maybe use %r instead of %s: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005159/when-to-use-r-instead-of-s-in-python

Comment: This is not really correct. _`__str__`_ is the output that is supposed to be human readable: `__repr__` is supposed to be a representation readable for the Python interpreter (i.e. feeding the string to the interpreter should recreate the object). If an object does not have a `__str__` method, however, `__repr__` is used instead. Also as noted: this example actually prints the `__str__` method of `self.x` and `self.y`: `%r` should be used instead of `%s` in the string formatting operation (since the class does not define `__str__`, `__repr__` is actually returned anyway, but it is an anomaly).

Comment: does every class implement repr in python?

Comment: There's a default `__repr__` for the `object` type that all types inherit from. So yes, but it's not that informative :)

Comment: It amazes me the way some languages make things more difficult than they should be. This should be named print or printable_representation etc. I swear Swift is the better version of Python...

Answer (score 23):

This is explained quite well in the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr):

> **repr**(*object*): Return a string containing a printable representation of an object. This is the same value yielded by conversions (reverse quotes). It is sometimes useful to be able to access this operation as an ordinary function. For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to `eval()`, otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object. A class can control what this function returns for its instances by defining a `__repr__()` method.

So what you're seeing here is the default implementation of [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__), which is useful for serialization and debugging.

Comment: I think the reverse quotes (or 'backticks') method of getting the "representation" of an object is deprecated, and was removed for version 3.0

Comment: MatrixFrog: both true, but the current 2.x documentation still says this, which is where the quote is from.

Comment: For many objects, _\_repr_\_ and _\_str_\_ are the same function. In fact, if you only define _\_str_\_, then _\_repr_\_ defaults to just calling _\_str_\_. The most obvious case where this is not true is strings themselves: str('stackoverflow') returns `stackoverflow` but repr('stackoverflow') is `'stackoverflow'`.

Comment: You have that backwards, \_\_repr\_\_ never uses \_\_str\_\_, but the reverse might happen. See http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.%5F%5Frepr%5F%5F

Answer (score 20):

`__repr__` is used by the standalone Python interpreter to display a class in printable format. Example:

```
~> python3.5
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class StackOverflowDemo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         pass
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return '<StackOverflow demo object __repr__>'
... 
>>> demo = StackOverflowDemo()
>>> demo
<StackOverflow demo object __repr__>
```

In cases where a `__str__` method is not defined in the class, it will call the `__repr__` function in an attempt to create a printable representation.

```
>>> str(demo)
'<StackOverflow demo object __repr__>'
```

Additionally, `print()`ing the class will call `__str__` by default.

---

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr), if you please

Answer (score 6):

The **__repr__** method simply tells Python how to print objects of a class

Comment: This is not true. That's what's `__str__` is for.

Answer (score 3):

An example to see the differences between them (I copied from [this source](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/__str__-vs-__repr)),

```
>>> x=4
>>> repr(x)
'4'
>>> str(x)
'4'
>>> y='stringy'
>>> repr(y)
"'stringy'"
>>> str(y)
'stringy'
```

The returns of `repr()` and `str()` are identical for `int x`, but there's a difference between the return values for `str`  `y` -- one is *formal* and the other is *informal*. One of the most important differences between the formal and informal representations is that the default implementation of `__repr__` for a str value can be called as an argument to eval, and the return value would be a valid string object, like this:

```
>>> repr(y)
"'a string'"
>>> y2=eval(repr(y))
>>> y==y2
True
```

If you try to call the return value of `__str__` as an argument to eval, the result won't be valid.

Answer (score -1):

Implement **repr** for every class you implement. There should be no excuse.
Implement **str** for classes which you think readability is more important of non-ambiguity.

Refer this link: [https://www.pythoncentral.io/what-is-the-difference-between-**str**-and-**repr**-in-python/](https://www.pythoncentral.io/what-is-the-difference-between-__str__-and-__repr__-in-python/)

Comment: Really?? Commanding others what to do? And on whose authority? Just make the case why a practice is good. People here can make up their own minds about what’s optimal for them in their particular circumstances.