# When to use %r instead of %s in Python?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

On [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) page 21, I see this code example:

```
x = "There are %d types of people." % 10
...
print "I said: %r." % x
```

Why is `%r` used here instead of `%s`?  When would you use `%r`, and when would you use `%s`?

Answer (score 351, accepted):

The `%s` specifier converts the object using [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str), and `%r` converts it using [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr).

For some objects such as integers, they yield the same result, but [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) is special in that (for types where this is possible) it conventionally returns a result that is valid Python syntax, which could be used to unambiguously recreate the object it represents.

Here's an example, using a date:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.date.today()
>>> str(d)
'2011-05-14'
>>> repr(d)
'datetime.date(2011, 5, 14)'
```

Types for which [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) doesn't produce Python syntax include those that point to external resources such as a `file`, which you can't guarantee to recreate in a different context.

Comment: I love this example, because it shows a big difference between %s and %r ... most examples just show something like 'apple' vs. apple, and then it's not clear why we even have %r.

Comment: How would one implement the % specifier in Python 3.3? I am also following the Learn Python the Hard Way sequence, but have found that there are a number of syntax differences between the Python versions.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why one might use the %r - but I now understand from your example above.

Comment: An important difference when using these in string formatting is that %r will also include the delimiting quotes. print('Text: %r' % 'Hello') -> Text: 'Hello', print('Text: %s' % 'Hello') -> Text Hello

Answer (score 20):

Use the `%r` for debugging, since it displays the "raw" data of the variable, 
but the others are used for displaying to users.

That's how `%r` formatting works; it prints it the way you wrote it (or close to it). It's the "raw" format for debugging. Here `\n` used to display to users doesn't work. `%r` shows the representation if the raw data of the variable.

```
months = "\nJan\nFeb\nMar\nApr\nMay\nJun\nJul\nAug"
print "Here are the months: %r" % months
```

Output:

```
Here are the months: '\nJan\nFeb\nMar\nApr\nMay\nJun\nJul\nAug'
```

Check [this example](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex6.html) from Learn Python the Hard Way.

Answer (score 16):

`%r` shows with quotes:

It will be like:

```
I said: 'There are 10 types of people.'.
```

If you had used `%s` it would have been:

```
I said: There are 10 types of people..
```

Comment: only true for strings, other types have different behavior

Comment: @Winston Ewert - of course, I was answering to the question's example, since in the example it was clearly used to produce the quotes.

Answer (score 14):

This is a version of Ben James's answer, above:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> x = datetime.date.today()
>>> print x
2013-01-11
>>> 
>>> 
>>> print "Today's date is %s ..." % x
Today's date is 2013-01-11 ...
>>> 
>>> print "Today's date is %r ..." % x
Today's date is datetime.date(2013, 1, 11) ...
>>>
```

When I ran this, it helped me see the usefulness of %r.

Comment: What does this add to his answer?

Comment: @fugu actually Gives an example of printing out using the `%r` and `%s` specifier, so users can see the differences more clearly.

Comment: Thanks @amanuel2 - exactly my intention.