# How to change the "gbk" into "uft-8"?

Tags: python

I tried to input and output Russian language in my file but failed it keeps displaying something like \xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82' when I run it in Terminal inside of python with  `print \xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'`

```
print "Привет!"
a = raw_input()
print "Как у тебя дела сегодня?"
a_1 = raw_input()
print "Понятно.Тогда у тебя есть планы вечром?"
a_2 = raw_input()
print "Пока."
a_3 = raw_input()
print "Давой завтра!"

print "Бывают люди бледные бывают тусклые бывают блестящие...Она только сказала \"%r\" \"%r\" \"%r\" \"%r\"... " %(
    a,a_1,a_2,a_3)
```

In Terminal:

```
MacBook-Pro:mystuff admin$ python ex11.py
Привет!
Привет
Как у тебя дела сегодня?
Нормально
Понятно Тогда у тебя есть планы вечром?
Да Я буду позвонить с другой 
Пока
Пока
Давой завтра
Бывают люди бледные бывают тусклые бывают блестящие...Она только сказала "'\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'" "'\xd0\x9d\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe'" "'\xd0\x94\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xaf \xd0\xb1\xd1\x83\xd0\xb4\xd1\x83 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd1\x81 \xd0\x98\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb9'" "'\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0'"...
```

Comment: `%r` calls `__repr__` on the string see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005159/when-to-use-r-instead-of-s-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

You should use`%s` instead of
`%r`.

What `%r` does is that it looks for a class function called `__repr__` of the object and returns `__repr__()`. You input a string `Привет`, and its `__repr__()` returns those hex numbers, which is the internal representation of the string.

If you use `%s`, it then looks for another function called `__str__`, and it will returns the string in the correct way.

Or you could use

```
print "Бывают люди бледные бывают тусклые бывают блестящие...Она только сказала \"{}\" \"{}\" \"{}\" \"{}\"... ".format(a,a_1,a_2,a_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

try `%s` instead of `%r`:

```
\"%s\" \"%s\" \"%s\" \"%s\"... " %(a,a_1,a_2,a_3)
```