# right usage of __repr__() in python?

Tags: python, file, repr

I have a container class which I would like to use to print all the elements in it.

I'd like to print them to file or console.

I've laid out the element (`Patch`) and container class as below and `__repr__(self)`.
I'm not sure I understood the purpose of `__repr__()` and am wondering whether the usage here is OK.

```
class Patch:
    def __init__(self, folder_name, file_name):
        self.folder_name = folder_name
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.full_path = os.path.join(self.folder_name, self.file_name)
        self.file_hash = md5_for_file(open(self.full_path, 'r'))
        self.file_size = os.path.getsize(self.full_path)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.file_name, self.file_hash, self.file_size)

class PatchContainer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.patch_folder_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
        self.patch_file_set = set()
    def addPatch(self, patch):
        if patch.file_name in self.patch_file_set:
            print '*** Delete the file ', patch.full_path, ' ***'
            return
        self.patch_file_set.add(patch.file_name)
        if not patch.folder_name in self.patch_folder_dict:
            self.patch_folder_dict[patch.folder_name] = [patch]
        else:
            self.patch_folder_dict[patch.folder_name].append(patch)

    def prettyPrint(self, writeable_object=PATCH_META_FILE):
        sys.stdout = writeable_object
        for patch_folder in self.patch_folder_dict.keys():
            print patch_folder
            patch_list = self.patch_folder_dict[patch_folder]
            for patch in patch_list:
                print patch
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

It works as intended but please comment on whether the style/usage are fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like you probably want `__str__`. They are similar, but `__str__` returns something intended for human consumption; `__repr__` should return something intended for Python consumption - it should either be a Python expression that will evaluate to an equal object, or something in angle brackets like the default `<classname object at id>`. See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) for the builtin `repr(object)`, which ends up calling `object.__repr__()`:

> For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that
>   would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval(),
>   otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets
>   that contains the name of the type of the object together with
>   additional information

Comment: Raymond Hettinger (@raymondh) tweeted on the subject the other day:  "When possible, `__repr__` methods should show how an object was constructed. The invariant should be: `eval(repr(obj)) == obj`."

Comment: how about prettyPrint() function? I could have defined PatchContainer's __str()__ instead of prettyPrint.

Comment: @Eugene yes. It would probably make more sense to do it that way, and so instead of calling `patchcontainer.prettyprint(file)` you would do `print >>file patchcontainer` (or `print(patchcontainer, file=file)` if you do `from __future__ import print_function`). It is almost always a good idea to separate business-level classes from the code that does IO.

Answer (score 2):

It's a human-readable representation of the object.

- "Purpose of Python's `__repr__`": [clicky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr)
- "Difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` in Python": [clicky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)
- Python documentation: [clicky](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)