# function and classes, usage of __str__

Tags: python, string, list, class, function

I am having some issues concerning the interaction between functions, methods and have a uncertainty of how to utilize the use of the built-in function `__str__`.

To start this of, I have a class called vara, which looks like:

```
class vara(object):

    def __init__(self, kod, namn, pris, butikantal):
        self.kod = kod
        self.namn = namn
        self.pris = pris
        self.antal = butikantal
```

and i have a function that creats a list of object for the vara klass, that looks like:

```
def mina_varor():

  varor_fran_fil = open("varor.txt", "r")
  varulista = []
  for rad in varor_fran_fil:
      varje_vara1 = rad
      varje_vara2 = varje_vara1.split("/")
      varorna = vara(varje_vara2[0], varje_vara2[1], varje_vara2[2], varje_vara2[3])
      varulista.append(varorna)

  return(varulista)
```

Now i want to be able to access a singel object in this list by simply typing then "kod" for the object. But I cant find any "kod" in my list. It seemed strange, so i tried printning the list, and got that:

`[<__main__.vara object at 0x00000000031503C8>, <__main__.vara object at 0x00000000031507F0>, <__main__.vara object at 0x0000000003150710>, <__main__.vara object at 0x00000000031502B0>, <__main__.vara object at 0x00000000031505F8>, <__main__.vara object at 0x00000000031504E0>]`

i looked it up, and it seems that python cant decide how to interpret my list. I think i need an `__str__` method to do so, but how should i make my `__str__` method look like if i want it to print something like:

```
Name: Hat
Price: 150
Quantity: 100
Code: 223
```

?

Comment: You want the `__repr__` magic-method. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1984177/42346

Comment: This is a good description of the differences between `__repr__` and `__str__`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1436756/42346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue 1: __str__() not being called when printing a container

It's not that Python can't interpret your list, its that it doesn't know how you expect it to be displayed.

Implement the `__str__` method if you want to do something like

```
print(varulista[0])
```

Something like the following would give you something like what you expect for that list entry:

```
def __str__(self):
    s  = "Name:    %s\n" % self.namn
    s += "Price:   %s\n" % self.pris
    s += "Quantity:%s\n" % self.antal
    s += "Code:    %s\n" % self.kod
```

But if you want `print(varulista)` to make any sense, you'll also have to implement the `__repr__` method, since `varulista` is a list and when printing it Python looks for the `__repr__` method.

But that being said, the idea of `__repr__` is to be able to pass it back into `eval()` and create an equivalent object.  So you could go one of two ways:

**1. Ignore the `__repr__()`/`eval()` interaction**

In this case, just implement `__repr__()` however you want.  Remember that this method is going to be called when it is an item in a container you're printing, so keeping the output to a single line might be helpful.  Just know that unless you unambiguously represent the state of the object in the `__repr__()` output, you won't be able to recreate an equivalent object "down the road" using `eval()`.

**2.  (Preferred option, IMO) Implement `__repr__()` correctly and simply don't print containers if you don't like the way it looks.**

If output like

```
[Item{Name:"Hat",Price:150,Quantity:100,Code:223},Item{Name:"Shirt",Price:450,Quantity:10,Code:225}]
```

is too unfriendly because of how you had to implement `__repr()__`, just don't print containers.  In other words, don't use

```
print(varulista)
```

but instead use

```
for item in varulista: print item
```

which would call the `__str__()` method you defined, the human-friendly one.

**EDIT:** @bernie's links to [a great answer by @AlexMartelli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python/1436756#1436756) regarding the difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` that is worth linking twice.

---

### Issue 2: being able to access a list element by it's code

You say

> Now i want to be able to access a singel object in this list by simply typing then "kod" for the object. But I cant find any "kod" in my list. It seemed strange, so i tried printning the list, and got that:

You have two main options here.  (1) Use a dictionary keyed on the item code. (2) Search through list for code using list comprehension.  I'm only going to show (1), because I think it's a much better alternative.

**Option 1: Use a dictionary keyed on the item code**

Consider this code:

```
# Define a convenience function to add items to the dictionary
def add_item(d,i): d[i.kod] = i

# Create a new dictionary
items = {}

# Add items to dictionary
add_item(items, vara(223, "Hat", 150, 100))
add_item(items, vara(225, "Shirt", 450, 10))
```

You can now access any defined item from the `items` dictionary as follows:

```
items[223] #<-- This is the "Hat" item
items[225] #<-- This is the "Shirt" item
```

Comment: Wow great help and well explained for someone like me who is pretty much a beginner at python! I only got 2 things I would like to ask you about. 1: I liked the idea about using for item in varulista, but you said that by doing so, i would call the __str__() method. I didnt see you calling it anywhere and got kind of confused. If i only make the for-loop, I won't call the __str__() method. I have to have some more code, right? 2: in the second part, about doing a dictionary. It would seem that i have to add each object to the dict. Can't i simply do a for-loop, that adds each line of my list

Comment: 1.  `__str__()` is implicitly called by Python when it tries to convert your `vara` object to a string.  So you don't need to call it, `print()` does it for you in that case.

Comment: 2. Yes, you would have to add each item in some way.  My suggestion was to skip the middle step of using the list, but if you have a list, a for loop like you describe would be fine.  Maybe: `for item in varulista: add_item(items, item)` or even just `for item in varulista: items[item.kod] = item`, the second option eliminating the use of the `add_item` convenience function.

Comment: Great help indeed! Have to try these out, will be back with some feedback after I have experimented a bit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Works like a charm, recommend people with similar promblem to try these   codes out!

Answer (score 0):

You could overide `__repr__` like this:

```
class vara():
    def __init__(self, kod, namn, pris, butikantal):
        self.kod = kod
        self.namn = namn
        self.pris = pris
        self.antal = butikantal

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Name: %s\nPrice: %s\nQuantity:%s\nCode: %s\n'\
               % (self.namn, self.pris, self.antal, self.kod)
```

output:

```
>>> print([vara('223', 'Hat', '150', '100'), vara('115', 'Bla', '154', '200')])
[Name: Hat
Price: 150
Quantity:100
Code: 223
, Name: Bla
Price: 154
Quantity:200
Code: 115
]
```

**Edit:**

But as explained by @jedwards, it is a better approach to override `__str__` just the same way I did for `__repr__` and print each object individually rather than printing the whole list.

Comment: This is not really a good approach but more of a lazy kluge.  It suggests breaking the contract of `__repr__()` for no reason / without any discussion about alternatives.

Comment: @jedwards No doubt that your answer is complete and informative but the OP may be looking for something simple to fix the problem quickly. My asnwer isn't wrong, is it? No need to vote down other answers to promote your own.

Comment: It's not to promote my own answer, but if you want to edit your answer (just add a space somewhere so I can revoke my vote), I'll revoke it for CoI.

Comment: @jedwards I see your point anyway, a little more explanation doesn't hurt. :)