# Printing the class object in python

Tags: python, openstack

I am working in modifications of codes in Openstack Designate.

During the same I need to print some data.

When I checked for type of the same, it returned the details as follows:

```
<class 'designate.openstack.common.rpc.amqp.RpcContext'>
```

When I tried to log the same (for printing), It is returning the details as follows:

```
<designate.openstack.common.rpc.amqp.RpcContext object at 0x7f7552b08250>
```

I know that it contains the tenant_id, So when I am trying to print the same it is working fine.

```
LOG.info(context.tenant_id)
```

Now I need to know or see what is inside:

```
<designate.openstack.common.rpc.amqp.RpcContext object at 0x7f7552b08250>
```

That is inside 'context'.

What I need is simply printing the details which resides inside 'context'

Comment: Ok... but what is the question?

Comment: Look up `__repr__` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anything related to oslo-incubator should be changed in openstack/oslo-incubator then synced to designate projects

however, most of the code has been graduated from oslo-incubator, the rpc module in oslo-incubator seems no longer exist, so it seems you are developing based on a (old) stable branch

so I guess you just need to find out what is in it.

as you already done for tenant_id, just add a log to print:

```
LOG.info('attr=%s, content=%s', dir(context), context.__dict__)
```

would be fine

Comment: context contains sensitive data, it is not recommend to print its content in log messages, my proposal should be only suitable for debug purpose.

Comment: Thank you.!! :) I am using this only for Debugging purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Read abount [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) and [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

`__repr__` is a "official" string representation of the object

`__str__` is a "informal" string representation of the object

You can overwrite both functions in a class.

For more info read [Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

In your case You can write:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%d' % self.tenant_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this little trick:

```
def info_obj(a):
    for x in dir(a):
        if not x.startswith('_'):
           print(x, ,'=', a.__getattribute__(x))
```

`dir(a)` will return the names of all the attributes of the object, and `__getattribute__` will get its value. I'm skipping the ones that start with `_` because these are usually not to be seen by users of the objects.