# how to get the value stored in the hex file location in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have classA wherein I have a get method to get the updated matrix, when I am trying to call the matrix in classB to print it out on console. I am getting something like

```
<packageA.prod.Cell.CellClass instance at 0x02C55558>,  
<packageA.prod.Cell.CellClass instance at 0x02C55580>,
```

How can I get the values stored in such location to be printed out?

How can I split such values, as I am getting a list of such values and as list cannot be split

Comment: You have the objects; each object has attributes and methods which you can access. And lists don't need to be split, you can access them by index.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thx mate, can you be bit more specific like what kind of method or attributes are we talking here. I mean to say is there any built in method that would help me in resolving  " packageA.prod.Cell.CellClass instance at 0x02C55558>"

Comment: I have no idea. What is CellClass? It's an object from your code. Your log is just showing the string representation of that class, but you have the actual object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the `__repr__` method in your class. Example:

```
class CellClass:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'Cell value: %s' % (self.value)
c = CellClass('cell text')
```

Output:

```
In [2]: c
Out[2]: Cell value: cell text
```

Credit/further reference:
[Purpose of Python's __repr__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr)