# Why is __repr__ called in the code below?

Tags: python

Can somebody please help me why the `__repr__` method is called with the `q.pop()` method in the code below?

```
>>> class Item:
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'Item({!r})'.format(self.name)
...
>>> q = PriorityQueue()
>>> q.push(Item('foo'), 1)
>>> q.push(Item('bar'), 5)
>>> q.push(Item('spam'), 4)
>>> q.push(Item('grok'), 1)
>>> q.pop()
Item('bar')
>>> q.pop()
Item('spam')
>>> q.pop()
Item('foo')
>>> q.pop()
Item('grok') 
>>>
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to put the code in the question not link copyrighted material

Comment: You will driving us crazy if you don't add the code to your question. Add an extra 4 spaces before every line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in `__repr__` function is used to return a printable format of an object. In this case, because `Item` is a custom object/class, the override in `__repr__` allows an instance of the `Item` to be displayed in the terminal. See when they call `q.pop()`, the item is printed to the screen, and this printing is done through the override of the `__repr__` function.

`q.pop()` prints `Item('bar')`because the overridden `__repr__` function for `Item` says to print `'Item({!r})'.format(self.name)`. This prints the word: `Item('')` and the format part fills in the actual contents of the item between the single quotes, thus resulting in `Item('bar')` being printed to the screen.

Read more about this here:
[Purpose of Python's __repr__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I read about __repr__ here before, but the thing that i can't see is where is exactly the explicit call for the __repr__ function. I mean if it would be a __del__  i could understand the explicit call because with the pop the object will be deleted. But the exact question is where the __repr__ is called through the pop()?

Comment: The `pop()` function returns an `Item`. When you call a function in python's `REPL` mode (that's when you run `python` in the terminal), any function's return value is printed to the screen. When the return value is printed, Python automatically calls `__repr__` to convert the object to a string that can be displayed to the user. This is the result that is shown on the screen. There is no explicit call to `__repr__`, but rather is a result of the python `REPL` evaluator.