# Set name of object in class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to set the name of a class to one of the variables within the class so that when I print classes I get their names, I've tried setting `__name__` but it did not work.

this is my class

```
class SNMPData(object):
    def __init__(self, device='', speed_down=0, speed_up=0, bgp_peer_state='', bgp_summary='', error=''):
        self.device = device
        self.speed_down = speed_down
        self.speed_up = speed_up
        self.bgp_peer_state = bgp_peer_state
        self.bgp_summary = bgp_summary
        self.error = error
        self.__name__ = device
```

I create a list of objects then try print them

```
>>> list = [SNMPData(device='dev_1',speed_down=1),SNMPData(device='dev_2',speed_down=2)]
>>> print(list)
[<SNMPData object at 0x7ff052a42ef0>, <SNMPData object at 0x7ff052a42b38>]
>>>
```

instead of SNMPData object at 0x.... is it possible to print

```
['SNMPData dev_1','SNMPData dev_2']
```

instead?

Comment: You are looking for [`__repr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr)

Comment: If the description is "small enough", it's recommended to restate how to create the object again, e.g. `SNMPData(device='{device}')`, but if it's going to be very state heavy, just do something generic `<SNMPData device={device} ...>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each class has a `__repr__` and `__str__` function which takes a single argument, `self`, representing the object itself. The `__repr__` function returns the true string representation of the object and the `__str__` function is used for `str(obj)` which is used for printing.

```
class SNMPData(object):
    def __init__(self, device='', speed_down=0, speed_up=0, bgp_peer_state='', bgp_summary='', error=''):
        ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.device)
```

You can do the same for `__str__(self)` if you want to observe this behaviour for printing.

Comment: Note that you don't need to hardcode `SNMPData`: you can use `self.__class__.__name__`.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking to define `__repr__` which should return a printable representation of the object. The [official definition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of `__repr__`

> repr(object):
>
> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object.
>   For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that
>   would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval(),
>   otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets
>   that contains the name of the type of the object together with
>   additional information often including the name and address of the
>   object. A class can control what this function returns for its
>   instances by defining a **repr**() method.

bottom line is that the output from **`__str__` is meant to be readable by human ** whereas the output from **`__repr__` is meant to be read by the Python interpreter.**  so when you give the string to the interpreter, it should recreate the object. Also If an object doesn't have a `__str__` method then `__repr__` is used instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are able to change a text representation of your custom object by overriding `__repr__` and `__str__` methods:

```
...
def __repr__(self):
    return self.__class__.__name__ + ' ' + self.device
```

Answer (score 1):

Define [`__repr__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) and [`__str__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__).

The former is the "official" string representation. The latter is what is returned when you cast the object to a `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing some of the other answers, you could do:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{self.__class__.__name__} {self.device}'.format(self=self)
```