# quantlib-python date method seems missing

Tags: quantlib

I am trying to run this in quantlib-python:

```
import QuantLib as ql
date = ql.Date(31, 3, 2015)
date
```

returning: `Date(31,3,2015)`

but it is supposed to return: `March 31st, 2015`

I am new to quantlib-python. What am I missing? Thank you.

I am using VC2015/quantlib 1.8/quantlib-swig-1.8

Answer (score 1):

When you only write `date`, your interpreter calls the `__repr__` method and displays the result. If you say `print date`, instead, it calls the `__str__` method, which is what you're looking for.  The two methods have different purposes in Python (see e.g. [Purpose of Python's __repr__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr)) and are often implemented differently; you can try the same thing with `datetime.date` and see what happens.

Comment: got it. Thank you.