# Python JSON format issue

Tags: python, json, xml, psd

```
<pixel: u'Crop Marks', size=2478x3509, x=1, y=0, visible=1, mask=None, effects=[]>
```

I got an output from a **psd parser** in Python.

Which type of format is this?

Comment: Looks like a custom [`__repr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr) implemented for that class.

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance of the `psd_tools.user_api.layers.PixelLayer` class of the psd_tools library. Everything in python is an instance of some type and therefore this. You can know it using the `type(<object>)` function.

Try `dir(<object>)` for seeing the list of attributes/ properties of that particular object. In your case, `dir(p)` where `p = <pixel: u'Crop Marks', size=2478x3509, x=1, y=0, visible=1, mask=None, effects=[]>` outputs,

`['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_channels',
 '_clip_layers',
 '_effects',
 '_index',
 '_info',
 '_mask',
 '_parent',
 '_psd',
 '_record',
 '_tagged_blocks',
 'as_PIL',
 'as_pymaging',
 'bbox',
 'blend_mode',
 'bottom',
 'clip_layers',
 'effects',
 'flags',
 'get_tag',
 'has_box',
 'has_clip_layers',
 'has_effects',
 'has_mask',
 'has_pixels',
 'has_relevant_pixels',
 'has_tag',
 'has_vector_mask',
 'height',
 'is_group',
 'is_visible',
 'kind',
 'layer_id',
 'left',
 'mask',
 'name',
 'opacity',
 'parent',
 'right',
 'tagged_blocks',
 'top',
 'vector_mask',
 'visible',
 'width']`

It is a list of all the attributes, functions or the properties you can access from the psd instance. We can see that a custom `__repr__` function has been defined for this which upon calling using `p.__repr__()` outputs the following format as a string `"<pixel: u'Crop Marks', size=2478x3509, x=1, y=0, visible=1, mask=None, effects=[]>"`. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: how to convert this  instance to json format or an xml format

Comment: You can try using `<object>.__dict__` which gives you a dictionary. But it doesn't seem like it is JSON serializable.