# EOF Error while using f-string in __repr__() function

Tags: python, string, eof, repr, f-string

I'm working in Python 3.x, and I'm trying to get an f-string to report from a `__repr__` function, but I can't seem to get the following formatted string to work the way I'm expecting it to.

I'm constantly getting "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f"Player has {'Soft' if self.soft > 0} {self.count}. Cards are {self.cards}."
```

The part that gives the error is {'Soft' if self.soft > 0}. And if it's not clear, I'm trying to include the word "Soft" IFF self.soft>0, if not, don't add any word to the string.

Comment: To be fair, that error message is quite misleading. The parser hasn't reached the end of the file (in any practical sense), but the end of the `{...}` block inside the f-string.

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr for the kinds of strings that `__repr__` and `__str__` should return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike the `if` statement, the `else` keyword in the conditional expression is not optional:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f"Player has {'Soft' if self.soft > 0 else ''} {self.count}. Cards are {self.cards}."
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.

Comment: Follow up question, what did you mean by the "if"  is optional?

Comment: Glad to be of help. I meant that in an `if` statement, the `else` block is optional, but in a conditional expression, even though it also uses the `if` keyword, the `else` portion of the expression is not optional. Was assuming that you omitted the `else` keyword simply because you drew parallel from the usage of the `if` statement.