# Common or pythonic __repr__ methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, repr

I usually write a `__repr__` as a way to show how the instance can be re-created in the first place. For example:

```
class Component:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(start={self.start}, end={self.end})'
```

Is there a 'standard' way to write the `__repr__`, if not, are there suggested options/best-practices for how this should be written, or it's totally subjective?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1984162/11301900, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/11301900

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general rule is, if at all possible, [produce output that could be typed to recreate the object; from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__repr__#object.__repr__):

> If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form <...some useful description...> should be returned.

The second part of that rule is mostly there just to make sure you don't make something that *looks* like a canonical recreating repr; in practice I've not seen it followed religiously.

For your specific case, I'd recommend only two tweaks:

1. If a `Component` might contain another `Component` as a `start` or `end` value, decorate the `__repr__` with [`reprlib.recursive_repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html#reprlib.recursive_repr) to avoid the possibility of infinite recursion in the case of a `Component` containing itself (important for libraries, where this might happen regardless of library author intention)
2. Explicitly use the `repr` of your attributes with the `!r` modifier (you don't want the "human friendly" string, you want a representation), changing the string to:

   ```
   return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(start={self.start!r}, end={self.end!r})'
   ```