# What is the difference between __repr__ and repr?

Tags: dictionary, repr

Why `__repr__` works and repr does not on a dictionary return?

class Person:
    name = ""
    age = 0

```
def __init__(self, personName, personAge):
    self.name = personName
    self.age = personAge

def __repr__(self):
    return {'name':self.name, 'age':self.age}
```

p = Person('Pankaj', 34)

print(p.`__repr__`())

print(repr(p))

OUTPUT:

{'name': 'Pankaj', 'age': 34}

Traceback (most recent call last):

...

```
print(repr(p))
```

TypeError: `__repr__` returned non-string (type dict)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the below I think option 2 returns an object, option 1 a string.

> The official Python documentation says **repr**() is used to compute the “official” string representation of an object. The repr() built-in function uses **repr**() to display the object. **repr**() returns a printable representation of the object, one of the ways possible to create this object.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-does-the-repr-function-do-in-Python-Object-Oriented-Programming

> Does print call str or repr?
>   str() displays today's date in a way that the user can understand the date and time. repr() prints “official” representation of a date-time object (means using the “official” string representation we can reconstruct the object).

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/str-vs-repr-in-python/

Comment: In https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-does-the-repr-function-do-in-Python-Object-Oriented-Programming, it says:
"__repr__() is used to compute the “official” string representation of an object ... __repr__()  returns a printable representation of the object" (1st para.)

It seems not clear.

Comment: As "The repr() built-in function uses `__repr__()` to display the object." in the first quote, repr & `__repr__` should have same result.

Comment: Please check if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr