# How to convert an object string to class object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently, I am trying to code a program in Python. I am struggling to make my system be able to decode str of classes:

E.g:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, coin):
        self.coin = coin

print(test(5))
>>> <__main__.test object at 0x00D20B10>
```

I would want to be able to convert the string to a class, then assign it to a variable so I can:

```
x = eval("<__main__.test object at 0x00D20B10>")
print(x.coin)
>>> 5
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    print(eval("<__main__.test object at 0x00D20B10>"))
  File "<string>", line 1
    <__main__.test object at 0x00D20B10>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you expect `eval("<__main__.test object at 0x00D20B10>")` to do?

Comment: to make it to a class type, like test()

Comment: You should implement `__repr__`.

Comment: If you're looking for serialization, you may be interested in [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to load an object from a file?

Comment: This quesrtion is not clear. Not even with the comments. Please edit it to explain better what do you want to do, eventually showing the result you wished to have.

Comment: You are probably looking for the [`__repr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr) method

Answer (score 0):

The terms "type" and "class" mean the same: Type of string is `str`; string is an object of the class `str`.

So you don't need to convert `str` "type" to `str` "class": `str` already *is* a (built-in) class.

---

*Note:*

`<__main__.test object at 0x00D20B10>` is a standard way how Python prints objects of classes. *It isn't an expression*, so applying the `eval()` function to it raises an exception (your error).

If you want print something else, implement the `__str__()` method in your class, for example

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "This is an object of my class Test."

print(Test())
```

The output:

> ```
> This is an object of my class Test.
> ```

Note that I used a *capitalized* name for your class — see [PEP 8 — Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the question. I think one of us misunderstood it :-)

Comment: OP still can't do `eval("This is an object of my class Test.")` so I don't see how that answers the question