# Clean way to combine instances from two different Classes into a new or modifed object

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, instance

Given instances from two different Classes in Python, I would like to combine them to produce either a new object which has "memory" of the combined objects or a modified instance that conserves its initial properties but develops new ones (as done here).

*Obviously, the example below is stupid, but is made for explanatory purposes.*

So I have the object `foo` (class `MainObject`) which should be combined with different instances of the class `OneNumber` (here, `a`, `b` and `c`). I need to:

1. keep the original objects (`a`, `b`, and `c`) or initial fields (of
   `foo`) unchanged;
2. keep track of these and use them (i.e., my final object should be able to use "inside itself" the initial `OneNumber` and `MainObject` instances to use their fields and produce new things, here through the `self.getNewNumber` method);
3. be able to call the relevant resulting combinations individually (i.e., here "1st" for the [`a`vs`foo`] combination, "2nd" for [`b`vs`foo`], etc.).

To address the 3 above, I create a dictionary to store individual combinations. Then, how to ideally create the keys? Obviously, it is suboptimal here. Giving a `self.name` field to the `OneNumber` class could be a better (?) option.

But I am sure real programmers must have a better way to do this all, right?

Would for example creating a new "combination" Class (with one instance of `OneNumber` and the instance of `MainObject` passed as arguments - three times to create three new objects, then) be better?

```
class OneNumber():
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.number = n

class MainObject():
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.number = n
        self.dic = {}
        self.newnumber = {}
        self.keys = ['3rd', '2dn', '1st']

    def combineOneNumber(self, onenum):
        combname = self.keys.pop()
        self.dic[combname] = onenum
        self.getNewNumber(combname)

    def getNewNumber(self, combname):
        self.newnumber[combname] = self.number + self.dic[combname].number


a = OneNumber(8)
b = OneNumber(13)
c = OneNumber(23)

foo = MainObject(2)
foo.combineOneNumber(a)
foo.combineOneNumber(b)
foo.combineOneNumber(c)
print(foo.newnumber)
# {'1st': 10, '2dn': 15, '3rd': 25}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not actually know the purpose of this code. But I change some parts of code, that may be helpful. If you want to write cleaner code, I suggest you read The "clean code" and "python tricks".

```
class OneNumber():
def __init__(self, number):
    self.number = number

def __repr__(self):
    return f"OneNumber({self.number})"


class MainObject():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        self.dic = {}
        self.new_number = {}
        self.keys = ['3rd', '2dn', '1st']

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'MainObject{self.new_number}'

    def comibne_numbers(self, *args):
        for number in args:
            combname = self.keys.pop()
            self.dic[combname] = number
            self.set_new_number(combname)

    def set_new_number(self, combname):
        self.new_number[combname] = self.number + self.dic[combname].number


a = OneNumber(8)
b = OneNumber(13)
c = OneNumber(23)

foo = MainObject(2)
foo.comibne_numbers(a, b, c)
print(foo)
```

Comment: Thanks. But appart from adding the `__repr__` method, what are you doing? And why are you doing this? Explaining the usefulness of adding `__repr__` and how/where you'd use it here would enhance your answer ;-) Sorry I was not clear in my question... Basically, I am looking for a way to "sum" or "combine" two Class instances into a new object with new properties but with memory of the "parents"...

Comment: Hi, please see this link to know the purpose of dunder repr in python. I hope it is helpful. Good luck.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr)