# how do i return float type when class instantiate in python?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to return float when class instantiated, like this :

```
class SMA:
"""
    Simple Moving Average

    fomula :
        sma = (a1+a2+a3+....) / n
"""
    def __init__(self,data_feed,time_period=None):
        self.data_feed = data_feed
        if not time_period:
            self.time_period = len(self.data_feed)
        else:
            self.time_period = time_period
        self.sma = sum(self.data_feed) / self.time_period

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.sma)

>>> b = SMA(data_feed=[1,2,3,4],time_period=4)
>>> print(type(b))
... float
```

but there is something wrong because 'b' has SMA type, not float

Comment: `float` is a built in class

Comment: This really doesn't make sense. When you instantiate the object, you always want to return it, not some other object. For what you want to do, you can just use a function that returns sme, instead of using a class.

Comment: You asked the same question a couple of hours ago, except it was `int`.

Comment: If you want `SMA(...)` to return a float, then `SMA` should be a function, not a class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to return integer when class instantiate in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66040641/how-to-return-integer-when-class-instantiate-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

`b` is the object of the class `SMA`, that is why it returns its class type.
to return a float value create a function

```
class SMA:
    def __init__(self,data_feed,time_period=None):
        self.data_feed = data_feed
        if not time_period:
            self.time_period = len(self.data_feed)
        else:
            self.time_period = time_period
        
    def get_value(self):
        return sum(self.data_feed) / self.time_period

b = SMA(data_feed=[1,2,3,4],time_period=4)
type(b.get_value())
```

`__repr__` returns a printable representation of the [object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr).

Answer (score -1):

Yours SMA() is constructor for SMA class, thus b variable being its objects.
For this type of operation i recommend reading about magic methods, dunder methods.

You may try overiding **str**(self).

Something like:

```
def __str__(self):
 return str(self.sma)
```